# Can you use Mantine Hooks without Mantine Core?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, mantine

I am making a site using Next.js and tailwind. To save time I am trying to find a hooks library. While researching I stumbled across Mantine UI. The mantine hooks library is exactly what I'm looking for, but I don't want to use their UI components.

Here's my question.

Is the Mantine hooks package dependent on Mantine Core or can I just install the hooks package?

If it is dependent, are there any other hook libraries you can recommend similar to Mantine Hooks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mantine/hooks it has no dependencies and you should be able to use it without the core package.

The examples on the project page do use the core package for their components to wire up a demo, here also - does not look like a hard dependency.

Comment: Thanks! I just happened to watch a video that says the hooks can be used by themselves.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQ9htM_LBVs